# How to pass a single @parameter(n) value to query in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I'm attempting to pass only @parameter(0) in the query in SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS). Passing @parameter works fine, but in a particular situation I want to pass only @parameter(0). I can display @parameter(n) in a text box just fine.

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM view 
-- WHERE a IN (@parameter) -- this works
WHERE a = @parameter(0) -- trying to make something along these lines work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click your dataset and choose 'properties'. The on the parameters tab, replace the @myParameter with the expression

```
=Parameters!myParameter.Value(0)
```

I've just tested this and it seems to work as expected

Comment: Thanks @alan-schofield. Seems obvious in hindsight. I kept at-parameter = [at-parameter] and added at-parameter = Parameters!myParameter.Value(0), and was able to call them out distinctly.

Comment: to be honest I had never done it before so I was interested in finding out! Everyday is a school-day!